# SharePoint 2010 Configuration Error Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Extended.Administration.Common.ExtendedSearchXmlContentMapProvider

Tags: 2010, search

I am getting following error when tring to browse the site
[image]

**Following is ULS Log**

> w3wp.exe (0x1760)                          0x1EB4  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Extended.Administration.Common.ExtendedSearchXmlContentMapProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)     at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolea... 6ebd18b0-0561-445b-a455-fd4aea5861ce
>   w3wp.exe (0x1760)                           0x1EB4  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...n throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)     at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)  6ebd18b0-0561-445b-a455-fd4aea5861ce

Comment: Please check the ULS logs to get more deatils

Comment: ULS log added as above